# Is there any method to connect Apache Poi and Apache Solr?

Tags: solr, apache-poi

I want to read my .csv file with apache poi and index the reading file in apache solr. I don't know is there any method this. I searched in google but I don't find any tutorial for this.

Comment: POI is not for .csv files. Usually TIKA and solr work nicely together for your issue.

Comment: I understand man thank u for your advice. @kiwiwings